# XML parsing loop through sublevels

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have XML in the following format:

```
 -<collection>
     -<beanRepresentation>
       <beanRepName>1</beanRepName>
       -<group>
        </group>
       -<relationships>
         <inputBeanId>1</inputBeanId>
         <outputBeanId>2</outputBeanId>
        </relationships>
       -<relationships>
         <inputBeanId>1</inputBeanId>
         <outputBeanId>3</outputBeanId>
        </relationships>
     </beanRepresentation>

     </beanRepresentation>
     <beanRepresentation>

   <collection>
```

I want to loop through each `<beanRepresentation>`'s and get the `<outputBeanId>`. Right now my code works when there is ONLY ONE  `<relationships>`, but the above XML, has two `<relationships>`'s. and I need to go in and get BOTH of the `<outputBeanId>`'s so I can put them into my function `connectPort()`.

```
$(window).load(function(){  
        var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
        $xml.find('beanRepresentation').has('outputBeanId').has('inputBeanId').each(function () {
        var $br = $(this);
        connectPort($br.find('beanRepName').text(), $br.find('outputBeanId').text());
        })
    });
```

This only works when is there only one `<relationships>`, how do I add a loop in here so I can get N amount of `<relationships>` to work.

Comment: There is no `beanRepId` in your XML but your try to find it in the jquery code..

Comment: sorry fixed. mistyped the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make another loop for each relationship

```
$(window).load(function(){  
    var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
    $xml.find('beanRepresentation').each(function () {
       var $br = $(this),
           relations = $br.find('relationships').has('outputBeanId').has('inputBeanId'),
           beanName = $br.find('beanRepName').text();

       relations.each(function(){
          var outputId = $(this).find('outputBeanId').text();
          connectPort(beanName , outputId);
       });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below:

```
$xml.find('beanRepresentation').each(function() {
      $(this).find('relationships').has('outputBeanId').has('inputBeanId').each(function(){
      // Blah Blah
      });
});
```

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: `$(window).load(function(){ 
    var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
    $xml.find('beanRepresentation').each(function () {
    $(this).find('relationships').has('outputBeanId').has('inputBeanId').each(function(){
        var $br = $(this);
        connectPort($br.find('beanRepName').text(), $br.find('outputBeanId').text());
     });
    });
   });`

not working for some reason.